# Output file for every input file in a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import csv
files=glob.glob('*.csv')
for file in files:
    df=pd.read_csv(file)
    a=sum(df.iloc[: , 0])
    with open ('output.txt','w') as f:
        f.write("sum of the first column is "+ str(a))
        f.close()
```

I would like to write output files for every input file that is in the folder. In output file i would like to have a info about a sum of the 1. column in every file. For ex. in a folder i have files[input1, input2,input3], i would like to make in the same folder files [otuput1,output2,output3] for every input file. In this code i got only one output file.

Comment: Side-note: `f.close()` isn't necessary; you (correctly) used a `with` block to open the file, so the moment execution leaves the `with` block (even if an exception is raised to do so), the file is automatically closed; the explicit `f.close()` is redundant. You only need to explicitly call `close` if you didn't use a `with` block (e.g. because the file was opened in one function call, and closed in another; this is relatively rare, with the `with` block being preferred in 99% of cases due to the risk of forgetting or bypassing manual `close` calls).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate output file for each input file and prefix/suffix it with the name of the input file -

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import csv
files=glob.glob('*.csv')
for file in files:
    df=pd.read_csv(file)
    a=sum(df.iloc[: , 0])
    output_file_name = "output_" + file
    with open (output_file_name,'w') as f:
        f.write("sum of the first column is "+ str(a))
        f.close()
```

If your input file is `input1.txt` - you will get a corresponding output file of `output_input1.txt`

Comment: Note: If there is any possibility that `output_SOMEFILE.csv` might exist, you can change the `open` mode to `'x'`, so it will raise an exception rather than overwriting the existing file's contents.